# "Skyrocket" in academic writing

Tags: academia

Would it be appropriate to use the verb `skyrocket` in an academic paper? 
 It sounds very colloquial to me, but as I'm not a native speaker I'm not sure.

If not, what is a good synonym I could use?

This is the sentence:

```
Managers’ decisions can be effective, and make profits and productivity skyrocket [...]
```

Comment: I'd avoid it. But this is just a matter of opinion, whichever way one feels.

Comment: If I use "increase dramatically", wouldn't somebody say it is too colloquial? It is just an opinion. I don't see any reason why you cannot use it.

Comment: I guess it is in fact a matter of opinion. I'll use it. Thanks.

Comment: or "rise sharply/steeply/exponentially".

Comment: Academic writing is not meant to be colorful; it's meant to be precise and clear. Using a sparkly metaphor like _skyrocket_ is nice, but exactly what are the facts, please? And just what is the trajectory? And how unusual is that? Etc. If you use a term that just says "Ooooh" instead of advancing the point (there has to be a point, or it isn't academic writing), it's not considered kosher.

Comment: What field?  Physics?  Probably not.  Sociology?  Maybe.  Lit-crit?  Surely.

Comment: Added more info to the OP.

Comment: I think it might be appropriate in a synopsis or summary, but not in the body of the paper.

Comment: Yes, it's in the introduction. I ended up using "skyrocket".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:n article in the Stanford Law Review is entitled: *Mental Hospitalization of Troublesome Youth: An Analysis of Skyrocketing Admission Rates*; an article in Rangelands is entitled *Skyrocketing trade deficits coupled with depletion of oil and natural gas ...*; an article in Phi Beta Kappan is entitled *The Cost of Skyrocketing Teacher Absenteeism*; an article in Reference & User Services Quarterly contains the sentence: "The intellectual life of retired faculty members, whose numbers will skyrocket in the coming years, can be ..."; an article in The American Journal of Economics and Sociology contains the sentence: "Land prices are a key element in the skyrocketing cost of both housing and food"; etc., etc. In short: It is not merely acceptable; it is also common.